# ASP.Net Web API authenticate users based on `[FromRoute]` parameter value

Tags: asp.net

I have sample API endpoints:

/foo/{group}/settings

/foo/{group}/users

I would like to authorized user based on the value of {group}. For example, UserA can only access endpoints `/foo/group1/settings` and `/foo/group1/users`. If UserA try accessing `/foo/group-other/users`, it will respond with HTTP 401 or, if {group} is not exists, HTTP 404.

The closest solution I have found is [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-6.0) however, I am not sure how I can passed in the value of `{group}`.

Is there any other way to achieve this? I am looking for something like having custom attributes that can be added to the controller methods wherever it is required.

P.S. This need to work on top of `[Authorize]` attribute.

Ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just read through the docs you linked.  For resource based auth, you define what you'll pass in to `_authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync`, so if the `Settings` object doesn't have its own `Group`, you could still just create a new custom class that has both and pass that in.

...That being said, you might look at policy-based authorization.  You can create custom auth handlers that get `IHttpContextAccessor` injected in to let you look up route values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement RBAC (Role-Based Access Control). Assuming "foo" is a controller, you can specify attributes on action-level for group 1, and so on.

```
public class foo : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "HRManager,Finance")]
    public IActionResult group1() =>
    Content("[Authorize]");
}
```

You should assign proper roles to each user. Assigning a role to a user means granting a specific "claim" the the user which will be kept in his cookie in encrypted form. [Authorize] attribute checks for those claims.

You can see documentation for detailed guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

In case you are having difficulties because of your custom structure, you can also consider manually checking claims within your actions like this (I would recommend this only as a last-resort as it reduces code readability):

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Note that "User" is inherited in controllers when using Identity.